# not able to run upgrades

Tags: upgrade, software-center, fonts

I am a new user trying to run upgrades in my new Ubuntu 12.04 , but i am running in to a problem all scripts seems to do fine and it gets to this screen

Package configuration

┌─────────────────┤ Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer ├─────────────────┐
 │                                                                           │
 │ TrueType core fonts for the Web EULA
 │
 │ END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT FOR MICROSOFT SOFTWARE
 │
 │ IMPORTANT-READ CAREFULLY: This Microsoft End-User License Agreement
 │ ("EULA") is a legal agreement between you (either an individual or a
 │ single entity) and Microsoft Corporation for the Microsoft software
 │ accompanying this EULA, which includes computer software and may include
 │ associated media, printed materials, and "on-line" or electronic
 │ documentation ("SOFTWARE PRODUCT" or "SOFTWARE"). By exercising your
 │ rights to make and use copies of the SOFTWARE PRODUCT, you agree to be
 │ bound by the terms of this EULA. If you do not agree to the terms of
 │ this EULA, you may not use the SOFTWARE PRODUCT.
 │

│
                                       ok
 │                                                                           │
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
 and hung there for  ever the "ok" is not active . i have wait hours it still the same, if i try to closed say that there is a process running and it will kill it.
it does the same with the dvd upgrade. 
thanks for youe help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make ttf-mscorefonts-installer package download fonts, after it says it installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463754/how-to-make-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-package-download-fonts-after-it-says-it-i)

Answer (score 3):

You agreed to install the restricted extras, so it's now installing Microsoft's core fonts and you have to accept the EULA to proceed.

Have you tried using the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to focus the "Ok" button?