# Ubuntu 14.10 upgrade stopped halfway

Tags: upgrade, 14.10

I had lots of problems trying to upgrade than it started. Now it has just stopped in Unpacking update-notifier-common (amd64). The system stills working well, some programs are having little problems and screenshot isn’t working. In the upgrade window, the terminal doesn’t close and is showing something about Microsoft fonts for Web (EULA). What should I do?

Comment: The EULA needs to be confirmed. If there are no buttons to do so, maybe pressing <kbd>Q</kbd> (should close the viewer with the EULA) and then <kbd>Y</kbd> (or maybe another key meaning 'yes' in your language; this should confirm the EULA) in the terminal will help.

Comment: There was no 'yes' key, I tried to type in terminal but it was blocked. I cancelled the upgrade, rebooted the computer, corrected the packages, autoclean, autoremove, sudo apt-get update and then upgrade. Finally, I made the dist-upgrade from terminal. It worked, and after this I was asked about EULA, and there was the 'yes' button. Now everything is okay about EULA. Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I accept the Microsoft EULA agreement for ttf-mscorefonts-installer?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16225/how-can-i-accept-the-microsoft-eula-agreement-for-ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't download ttf-mscorefonts-installer on ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/463754/cant-download-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but once I clicked in the small line at the bottom of the window which appeared to be showing a small part of the terminal interface, I was able to use the keyboard tab key to move to and highlight the  option, then press enter. This appears to have continued the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get past this, pressing tab brought up the yes/no dialogue so managed to accept the (unread) EULA and move on.