# Problem installing Microsoft font

Tags: software-center, fonts, microsoft

When I tried to install **Microsoft** fonts from my Ubuntu software center, it says it installed okay. But when I open *writer* there is no Microsoft font appear in font list. I reinstall it but it's not worked for me.

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `fc-match Arial`

Comment: And the output of `apt-cache policy ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in LibreOffice Writer to see if the following Microsoft True Type Core Fonts have been installed:

⠀Andale Mono
⠀Arial Black
⠀Arial
⠀Comic Sans MS
⠀Courier New
⠀Georgia
⠀Impact
⠀Times New Roman
⠀Trebuchet MS
⠀Verdana
⠀Webdings

If all of these fonts appear in the font list in LibreOffice Writer, then the Microsoft True Type Core Fonts have been installed successfully. If not, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463754/how-to-make-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-package-download-fonts-after-it-says-it-i/463760#463760)