# ttf-mscorefonts-installer fails to update. Unistall/ install

Tags: updates, uninstall

I am sure, this is going to be a duplicate thread, but believe me, I tried out all the original ones In fact. Whenever my system starts up, I am welcomed with this message below:

[image]

I searched all the forums, reinstalled, restarted, uninstalled an installed again, rebooted, completely removed including folder and cache. Tried everything that' literally found in the forms, I tried rebooting after I done all these works arounds. Yet no hope, this annoying thing pops up and makes my day worse. Any help largely appreciated. Almost 20+ solutions I tried one after another btw.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved here:
https://askubuntu.com/a/667542/530893

To quote the actual solution:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/*
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Please don't link to answers somewhere else on this site but flag the existing question as a duplicate! (already done)  **;-)**

Comment: (also review my edits of the question on how to insert screen shots)  **;-)**