# Synaptic Error: W: Can't drop privileges

Tags: 16.04, permissions, synaptic

I realize this has already been sort of asked, but the question I found was related to fonts rather than Synaptic in general.

Every time I run anything in Synaptic, everything installs perfectly fine but then I receive this error:

```
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file
'/root/.synaptic/tmp//tmp_sh' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. -
pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

I'm not certain how this is fixed, especially since I neither have a user named `_apt` nor do I have any files at all in `/root/.synaptic/tmp/`.

Even though this error does not seem to effect anything, I'd still like to fix it just in case it actually is doing something I'm not seeing behind the scenes.

Comment: The answer is similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/771936/permission-error-when-installing-ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Comment: More info: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/1543280

Comment: This looks like a warning, not an error.