# Ubuntu 22.04 When I use "sudo apt install ./xxxx.beb" , I received a warning... ( ... couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. )

Tags: apt

I downloaded the "chrome" deb package (under folder ~/Downloads). Then I open terminal, go to ~/Downloads and run "sudo apt install ./googlexxxxxx.deb". I got a Warning. (as what I presented in the picture)

However, if I move the .deb file to /home/. Then run "sudo apt install ./xxx.deb". Everything goes well, no warning.

Is there anyone knows the problem? I just installed unbuntu 22.04 and found this problem when I tried to install chrome.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/771936/permission-error-when-installing-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-cant-drop-privileges

Comment: Please try: `sudo dpkg -i google*.deb` Apt means, roughly, "Go out to the Ubuntu repositories and install the package and, if needed, all of its dependencies." That's not what you are trying to do. Dpkg means, roughly, "Install this package that I've already downloaded."