# Upgrade from 14.02 to 16.04 hangs at ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

Using the distribution upgrade for 14.02 to 16.04, the upgrade has frozen at "Configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer" because no button(s) came up to allow me to OK the EULA. Cannot open a new terminal to attempt recovery, no response to open terminal. Hate to pull the power on the machine, can't think of another alternative. Need suggestions, please.

Comment: Hit the TAB key. And before making an answer this has been asked before and a few times even ;) Example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/463754/how-to-make-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-package-download-fonts-after-it-says-it-i

Answer (score 0):

I found the easy solution from another post relating to the same issue: simply hit Tab, then Enter, you will be asked for a Yes or No. Upgrade proceeds normally after this. Too bad instructions to "Hit Tab" aren't present, but such is life.