# Cannot install the package ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Tags: 16.04, .ttf

These are the problems shown on the terminal:

```
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/andale32.exe' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/arial32.exe' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

Similarly many other files related to ttf-mscorefonts-installer.

Answer (score 33):

The one that SOLVED the problem was a manual install (@rag2):

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

Details:
https://gist.github.com/melvincabatuan/26f3ac4ace4be3a8b48d85a1b3250982

Unfortunately, [the following answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/829248/300654) didn't work for me (in Ubuntu 16.04).

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/*
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Result:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  ubuntu-core-launcher
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/29.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 286132 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu2_all.deb ...
mscorefonts-eula license has already been accepted
Unpacking ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) over (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.11.94-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for update-notifier-common (3.168.3) ...
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: processing...
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
Get:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe [361 B]
Err:1 http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe                  
  404  Not Found
W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/andale32.exe' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to fetch https://ncu.dl.sourceforge.net/project/corefonts/the fonts/final/andale32.exe  404  Not Found

E: Download Failed
Setting up ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2) ...
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is [the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/msttcorefonts/+bug/1607535) on launchpad. The cause of the bug is http redirects on `sourceforge.org` which are not handled properly by the installer.

The [author](https://launchpad.net/~robingape) of the report provides two workarounds with detailed walkthrough:

- The one is to cherrypick v3.6 from debian site as mentioned in other answers.
- The other is to manually download  the required files from sourceforge with `wget` which can handle the redirects nicely,
  then run `dpkg-reconfigure` and specify the directory with the downloaded files when asked.

Make a temporary directory and download fonts:

```
mkdir /tmp/mscoref
cd /tmp/mscoref
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/{andale32.exe,arial32.exe,arialb32.exe,comic32.exe,courie32.exe,georgi32.exe,impact32.exe,times32.exe,trebuc32.exe,verdan32.exe,webdin32.exe}
```

then purge the failed package

```
sudo apt-get purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

reinstall the package ignoring probable errors:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

and finally:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

this will lead to this message:

[image]

Press `enter`; type the path to the downloaded files in the box (note: `.` does not work for me here):

[image]

and press `enter` again.

Now the fonts get installed smoothly:

```
....
Extracting cabinet: /tmp/mscoref/webdin32.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting Webdings.TTF
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Licen.TXT

All done, no errors.
All fonts downloaded and installed.
```

**All credits should go to [robingape from launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~robingape)**

Comment: this looks nice, but where can I enter the path? I doenst ask for this

Answer (score 10):

The version 3.4 of the ttf-mscorefonts-installer is currently broken. Version 3.6 from the Debian repositories works fine. You can download and install the package accordingly (and thereby fix the error mentioned above):

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

Alternative regional repositories are at https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/download.

This has fixed the above mentioned bug for me.

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 14.04 after I installed cabextract with: 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly this bug is a bug of `apt` and not `dpkg` or `wget`. You can circumvent this by downloading in case of 16.04 (xenial)

http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/download

and install it manually as:

```
ubuntu@green: $ cd Downloads
ubuntu@green:~/Downloads $ dpkg --install ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.6_all.deb
```

Comment: That URL leads to the package ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4+nmu1ubuntu2_all.deb which still cannot be installed with dpkg. The 3.6 version does work (at least for me), on the other hand.

Answer (score 0):

Use this commands to fix problems:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/*
sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer\
```

Check other solutions here: [How to make ttf-mscorefonts-installer package download fonts, after it says it installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463754/how-to-make-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-package-download-fonts-after-it-says-it-i)

Comment: This answer still results in a failure: W: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial/andale32.exe' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)