# Strange UI behavior (missing fonts, old GTK look-like windows, ...)

Tags: unity, fonts, gui

My problem is really strange and I cannot even describe it perfectly. It happened about last week after some big Ubuntu update and after I restarted the PC few days later. After the restart I realized these changes:

- missing a lot of fonts that were previously present

  - realized when texts were displayed in strange way
- some UI windows look like from old GTK times
- in some UIs font is not rendered at all and accidentally appears or disappears...

[image: GTK look-like window in unity]
[image: SoapUI with missing texts]
[image: SoapUI with texts OK]

First I thought it might be something with `wine` since I had the `wine-devel` installed but even after uninstalling `wine-devel` and installing back `wine1.6` the problem is not solved. Also tried to uninstall `wine` completely without a solution.

Some thing are minor, like these GTK looking like windows, or that some font's are gone and I have to use some *not so fancy Ubuntu fonts*, but the thing with SoapUI for example just makes it almost not usable...

Any idea how to solve the problem?

**EDIT:**

I still think it's wine, because when using **file upload form**, the UI looks like on the first picture, and then the filled in *file path* is like `C:\fakepath\[Filename]`, i.e. if I am uploading a file `/home/shadyyx/Desktop/picture.png`, the file path in the *file upload* input field is shown like `C:\fakepath\picture.png` (correct file is uploaded, so no functional impact).

Comment: Looks very strange indeed. Have you installed any other desktop environments? I'm not too sure, but when I installed additional environments, it started to mess around with the others

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. If I did (by myself), I would have known about it and that would be the first option to check. The other first is still this wine. Is it possible it somehow installed something by itself? How can I check? I still think it's wine, because when using **file upload form**, the UI looks like on the first picture, and then the filled in *file path* is like `C:\fakepath\[Filename]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I have fixed my problem. I tried to reinstall unity using

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

which only downloaded 3k of bytes and after the `sudo reboot` the problems are apparently gone.

After restart I also got a *warning* about [the mscore ttf font installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829247/cannot-install-the-package-ttf-mscorefonts-installer) and after trying to fix this as well it seems everything is back to normal...

I am almost convinced *wine* broke something (especially after *upgrade* from stable win 1.6 to devel wine 2.1).

I hope this helps somebody trying the same wine upgrade and struggling with similar issues afterwards...