# Cannot access windows fonts after installing them on Ubuntu WSL

Tags: fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to get Microsoft Windows' `Copperplate Gothic` font on my Ubuntu subsystem using WSL. I followed the instructions in [this link](https://itsfoss.com/install-microsoft-fonts-ubuntu/) and the installation seemed to go fine. However, when I run `fc-list | grep "Copperplate"` I get no results. When I run `fc-list | grep "New Roman"` I also get no results.

How can I access my newly installed windows fonts on my Ubuntu subsystem via the command line?

Comment: Yes, I would like to stick to WSL and the command line, if possible. Here's my use case https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610544/can-i-get-ms-word-font-on-tex

Comment: I want to compile a TeX document from within WSL which makes use of the Copperplate Gothic font, as indicated in the question posted on LaTeX StackExchange. For this reason, I seek to make Copperplate Gothic available to my Linux Subsystem. I don't care about the terminal font.

Comment: I don't believe I should. All context relevant to the question is included. The problem is outside of the scope of TeX. If I can `fc-list` my Copperplate Gothic font, then I can access it from TeX. There's no need to clutter this question with the TeX related details, they are irrelevant here.

Comment: Adding context and details helps others understand the problem and increases your chances of getting an answer. Comments are temporary in nature and people should not have to read through extended comments in order to understand your question. Editing your question so that the problem is clear and detailed is the best way to help yourself and increase your chances of getting a relevant answer

Comment: I think the question is clear and detailed enough. I only provided information about the use case because you were curious about it. A person with enough Ubuntu experience, specifically regarding `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` should be able to help me figure out what is going wrong with the information provided. The questions you are asking me are slightly off topic, and do not help in my opinion. You're asking me more about *why* I want to solve the issue rather than providing insight on *how* to go about solving it....

Comment: Good to hear you got it working.  A side note - While I like the fact that you want to keep the question clean and minimal, there are (at least) two reasons that, like @Nmath, I like to know the "why" behind questions here.  First, there's often an orthogonal answer to many questions asked on Stack - A way to solve the "why" differently than the "what" that was asked.  Second, I find quite often that solving the "what" ends up not solving the OP's real problem, *especially* on WSL where there are a lot of nuances involved.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the installation did not go as well as I thought. Perhaps I did not accept the Terms during the first installation. I ran the following set of commands:

```
sudo apt remove ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo dpkg -P ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo fc-cache -f
```

Now `fc-list | grep "New Roman"` provides me with a variety of fonts based on Times New Roman, so I think it worked.

The `dpkg` command comes from [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463754/how-to-make-ttf-mscorefonts-installer-package-download-fonts-after-it-says-it-i), I'm not sure why it's necessary.